# ESX 3.5 refuses to update

Tags: vmware-esx, update, patch-management, metadata

I have a set of ESX 3.5 servers in 2 different datacenters. One is DR, one is production. They are on the same vlan and so I can access any of them on the private network from my vCenter server. Last month, as a learning experience (I hadn't dealt with ESX much before), I updated the DR server.

Other than finding out that a couple of bundles had to be installed manually in order to get the rest to install from vCenter, it went off without a hitch.

Now, I'm trying to do the same for our production servers and it is not working. I've googled around for the error I get during scan, and investigate loads of different solutions (editing the integrity file, checking DNS, etc) -- I did install the 2 bundles that had to be installed manually already -- but scan from vCenter is just not working.

Side note: I did just scan the DR server again and that scan works fine so shouldn't be a problem with vCenter that has cropped up recently -- it has to be something else.

The error I get is:

```
Patch metadata for (servername) missing. Please download updates metadata first.
Failed to scan (servername) for updates.
```

I'm all out of ideas on how to make this work, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working for 3 of the 4 hosts, thus far. The last one has hardware issues and will likely be successful once that is corrected.

After a lot of rigimarole, it was determined that the hosts were running different patch levels, but yet somehow had all been successfully added to a cluster. In trying to troubleshoot a problem where one of the hosts wouldn't reconfigure for HA, we went ahead and updated (manually) to 3.5 Update 5a, and then manually installed the following two bundles:

ESX350-201012404-BG
ESX350-201012410-BG

After rebooting the host and the vCenter server, we were able to add the baseline again and successfully scan for updates.